# Xcode 6 user experience guidelines for Apple app store submission

Tags: objective-c, ipad, user-experience, ios8.1

I have an iPad Application which is developed with iOS 6 UX guidelines/ style. Now I upgraded this app to iOS 8 SDK by fixing all UI alignment issues and app is ready.

If I submit this app which is not compatible with flat look iOS 8 UX, will Apple approve my app? I tried finding UX Guidelines for app store submission but couldn't find concrete info. How can I understand what is expected in terms of UX?

Comment: All apps submitted to the app store whether new or updates must have the iOS7/8 flat UI. They must be compatible with iOS7/8 and you comply with the UI guidelines for them. Also if you build it for iOS7/8 now it should have the new flat UI design and not the iOS6 version.

Comment: Thanks for immediate response and inputs.. You are right as default controls are updated to new iOS 8 style but app is having lot of images which is mapped to iOS6 UI Style.

Comment: Why are you wanting to live in the past with the old style?